# Measure-Theoretic Importance Sampling: Do we need equivalence of measures?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, sampling

Let $\pi$ and $\mu$ be the target and proposal measures on $(X, \mathcal{X})$ respectively, with $\pi \ll \mu$. Suppose $\lambda$ is the reference measure on $(X, \mathcal{X})$ and that $\pi\ll \lambda$ and $\mu\ll\lambda$ with densities
$$
\frac{d \pi}{d\lambda} = \frac{\tilde{p}_\pi}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\pi \, d\lambda} \qquad \qquad \frac{d \mu}{d \lambda} = \frac{\tilde{p}_\mu}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\mu d\lambda}
$$
I would now like to find the usual expression for the Importance Sampling weights. For this, I consider the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\pi$ with respect to $\mu$
$$
\begin{align}
W = \frac{d \pi}{d \mu} 
&= \frac{d \pi}{d \lambda} \frac{d \lambda}{d \mu} && \text{Chain rule requires $\pi \ll\lambda \ll \mu$} \\
&= \frac{d \pi}{d\lambda} \left(\frac{d \mu}{d \lambda}\right)^{-1} && \text{This requires $\lambda \ll \mu$ and $\mu \ll \lambda$ i.e. equivalence} \\
&= \frac{\tilde{p}_\pi}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\pi \, d\lambda} \cdot \left(\frac{\tilde{p}_\mu}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\mu d\lambda}\right)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{\tilde{p}_\pi}{\tilde{p}_\mu} \cdot \left(\frac{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\mu d \lambda}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\pi d\lambda}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Which makes sense because this agrees with the usual set-up. However, for this to work, we must have $\mu$ and $\lambda$ equivalent, but surely this is **never** the case in practice?

> Is this derivation correct?  I.e. do we need $\mu\ll\lambda$ and $\lambda \ll\mu$ to get our usual Importance Sampling weights?

Comment: Notice that the reference measure $\lambda$ would just be the usual Lebesgue measure $dx$

Comment: Also notice that $W: X\to [0, 1]$ is the *normalized* weight function while $w:X\to [0, +\infty)$ is the *unnormalized* weight function given by
$$
w(x) = \frac{\tilde{p}_\pi(x)}{\tilde{p}_\mu(x)}
$$
Expectations are then 
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_\pi[\phi] = \int_X \phi d \pi
&= \int_X \phi \frac{d \pi}{d \mu} d\mu  \\
&= \frac{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_{\mu}(x) dx}{\displaystyle \int \tilde{p}_\pi(x)dx}  \int_X \phi(x) \frac{\tilde{p}_\pi(x)}{\tilde{p}_\mu(x)} \tilde{p}_\mu(x) dx
\end{align}
$$

Comment: And if we sample $X^{(1:N)}\sim\mu$ we have the particle estimate
$$
d\mu^N(x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{X^{(i)}}(dx)
$$

Comment: The expectation is then 
$$
\mathbb{E}_\pi[\phi] = \frac{\displaystyle \int_X \phi w d\mu}{\displaystyle \int_X w d \mu} \approx \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N \phi(X^{(i)})w(X^{(i)})}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N w(X^{(i)})} = \sum_{i=1}^N \phi(X^{(i)}) W(X^{(i)})
$$

Comment: We can always get the expression above, even if $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are not equivalent. However, the expression for the normalized weights is only given by the usual formula when $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are equivalent

Comment: This seems somewhat strange. Just write $W=\frac{d \pi}{d\mu}$ or $w=W\frac{\pi(X)}{\mu(X)}$ and check that you get the right expectations. You don't need $\lambda$ at all. And if you insist, assume $\mu, \pi << \lambda$ to get $p_\mu, p_\pi$ and again check the resulting expectations.

Comment: @Max I agree that $W$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\pi$ by $\mu$ and requires $\pi \ll \mu$, but in **practice** when you need to perform Importance Sampling, you usually evaluate the weights as the ratio of their densities
$$
W(x) = \frac{\pi(x)}{\mu(x)}.
$$
This requires both $\pi$ and $\mu$ being absolutely continuous with respect to the reference measure $\lambda$. But it also requires equivalence of $\lambda$ and $\mu$, otherwise one cannot write the ratio that way.
$$
\frac{d\pi}{d\mu} = \frac{d\pi}{d\lambda} \cdot \frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}
$$
and we need to invert the second.

Comment: @Max I am looking at [this section of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Properties)  and you can see that the chain rule requires $\pi\ll\lambda\ll \mu$ to work. That is, if $\pi\ll\lambda\ll\mu$ then 
$$
\frac{d\pi}{d\mu} = \frac{d\pi}{d\lambda}\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu} \qquad \mu\text{-almost everywhere}.
$$
and inversion requires $\lambda \ll\mu$ and $\mu\ll\lambda$ so that
$$
\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu} = \left(\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\right)^{-1} \qquad \mu\text{-almost everywhere}.
$$
Of course if $\mu$ has a density wrt $\lambda$, we know $\mu\ll\lambda$.

Comment: Don't use the chain rule. Take the final formula, with minimal assumptions needed to make it make sense. Then check that using that formula produces the right expectation. It does not matter for the formula's validity how you got the formula; if you can check that it works, it works.

Comment: @Max I’m sorry I’m not sure what you mean exactly. Do you mind writing an answer?